# Bug: Google Analytics 4 UI first_open Android datastreams

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-4

**Problem**

Event first_open missing from Android platform in Google Analytics 4 UI.

**Reproduction**

- Mobile App released on 26.2.2024
- We wanted to check first_open events and they were missing in GA4 report
  [image]
- Events are being reported in BigQuery export for Android, iOS
  [image]
- Comparing same date ranges, same datasets and properties
- Android Firebase SDK bom version: 32.7.0

**What I have tried**

- Other available APIs in GA4 UI - such as Explorer section. Same result.
- Change Reporting Identity in GA4 to device-only - didn't help

I am assuming that this is **bug** in GA4 UI or API itself.